# CPU load graph with history per process for Linux

Tags: linux, system-monitor

I am looking for a CPU (possibly other resources) chart (being continually drawn) where I can hover/click on any place in history (e.g. spike) and it shows me which processes were using which cores, e.g. at 17:57:05 most of CPU were using Firefox with 25% of core #1, 0% of core #2 (other processes following, at least few top ones).

Something similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Prometheus/Grafana combination. [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) is for collecting data (and some visualisation), [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) is for visualization + dashboards.

Installation and configuration can take a while, though.

The [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) monitoring tool is still in the ubuntu repositories, I think, but it only gives you plots (no drill-down information)